# Angular 5 : how to dynamically bind events on button from a list

Tags: angular5

```html
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in" style="text-align:left;opacity: 1;" >
   
  <button *ngFor="let tool of toolArray" class="m-btn btn btn-secondary" type="button" (click)="{{tool.ToolMethod}}()" placement="bottom"
      ngbTooltip="{{tool.Tooltip}}">
      <img src={{tool.ToolImgPath}} alt="" width="24" height="24"/>
  </button>

</div>
```

Lets say , I have some tools managed by admin , if the user logs in , he can use that tools for editing .

```
 let toolArray = [
    {ToolCategory: "analysis"
    ToolId: 96
    ToolImgPath: "images/zoom-selection.png"
    ToolMethod: "zoomToClickedFeature"
    ToolName: "an_zoomto_selected"
    Tooltip: "Zoom To Selected Feature"}
]
```

if I add this in the html using ngFor , its getting error like

```
Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method is a member of the controller, you should use `this` like: `(click)="this[tool.ToolMethod]()"`.

Here's a working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2l54d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: but how to handle error  if the tool Method is not present in the component ? getting this error ERROR TypeError: _co[_v.context.$implicit.ToolMethod] is not a function ,if we forget to define the method

Comment: You could check for undefined before calling `(click)="this[item.method]&&this[item.method]()"`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the curly brackets from `(click)="{{tool.ToolMethod}}()"` to `(click)="tool.ToolMethod()"` and refactor your code to something like this, to get the reference to the corresponding method right:

```
public zoomToClickedFeature() {
  console.log("do something");
}

public toolArray = [
  {
    ToolCategory: "analysis",
    ToolId: 96,
    ToolImgPath: "images/zoom-selection.png",
    ToolMethod: this.zoomToClickedFeature,
    ToolName: "an_zoomto_selected",
    Tooltip: "Zoom To Selected Feature"
  }
];
```

Array and function must be class properties of the component.